# Lua goto back to for loop

Tags: for-loop, lua, goto

i have problem with Lua goto.
An error occurs after running the script :
undefined label **'back'**

Code:

```
function determinant()
det = 1
for k = n, 2, -1 do
    if a[k][k] == 0 then
        goto skok_jedna
    end
    ::back::
    for l = 1, k-1 do
        for m = 1, k-1 do
            a[l][m] = a[l][m] - a[l][k] * a[k][m] / a[k][k]
        end
    end
    det = det * a[k][k]
end
det = det * a[1][1]
goto konec_det

::skok_jedna::
l = k

::skok_dva::
l = l - 1
if l == 0 then
    det = 0
    return
end

if a[l][k] == 0 then 
    goto skok_dva
end

for m = 1, k do
    c[n] = a[l][m] 
    a[l][m] = a[k][m]
    a[k][m] = c[m]
end

det = det * -1
goto back 
::konec_det::
end
```

The script is part of a program to calculate a system of linear equations of n-variables using Cramer's rule.

Where is problem ? Thx all for reply

Answer (score 4):

The Lua manual says:

1. A label is visible in the entire block where it is defined, except inside nested functions.
2. A goto may jump to any visible label as long as it does not enter into the scope of a local variable.

What's going on in your code:

1. The label `back` is invisible from the line `goto back`
2. You're jumping inside the scope of loop variable `k`

Answer (score 0):

Thx for reply.
I solve this problem with second function (remove goto from for-loop and goto back to for-loop):

```
function determinant()
det = 1
for k = n, 2, -1 do
    if a[k][k] == 0 then
        det2 {k}
        if det == 0 then
            return
        end
    end

    for l = 1, k-1 do
        for m = 1, k-1 do
            a[l][m] = a[l][m] - a[l][k] * a[k][m] / a[k][k]
        end
    end
    det = det * a[k][k]
end
det = det * a[1][1]
end

function det2(k)
l = k
::skok_dva::
l = l - 1
if l == 0 then
    det = 0
    return
end
if a[l][k] == 0 then 
    goto skok_dva
end
for m = 1, k do
    c[n] = a[l][m] 
    a[l][m] = a[k][m]
    a[k][m] = c[m]
end
det = det * -1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't jump inside for loop. It's not Lua's problem. For loop is a scope, that in your case has local variable "k" that is initialized at the beginning on the scope, before you "back" label. What do you even want your code to do? After jumping to ::back:: literally the next line is "for l = 1, k-1 do" - but variable "k" doesn't exist. So what exactly do you expect you code to do with that?
That's why simple languages like Lua/Java/Python where you don't declare variables or their types are so horrible for programmers. People who use them have no idea what their program is doing. You need to have clear understanding of variables, scopes, etc.